Homeomorphism from open ball to $\mathbb{R^2}$
In the following answer, the following homeomorphism is presented from the unit ball to $\mathbb{R^2}$:
$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{1-r}, \theta\right)$$
However, I believe that this only shows that the ball is homeomorphic to the complement of it. Suppose I have a point inside the ball in $\mathbb{R^2} $, eg: $(.5,120^°)$ then which point from the ball gets mapped into it?

Thanks for finding that out and trying to get a correction through in the linked post. Since we are on the case: What do you think about the fact that the origin has no polar coordinates?

The spelling is "homeomorphic".

The "map"
$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{1-r}, \theta\right)$$
is not well-defined at the origin - which value of $\theta$ has to be taken?
Also its corrected version
$$(r,\theta) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{1-r}-1, \theta\right) = (\frac{r}{1-r},\theta)$$
is not unproblematic because we need to prove that it it continuous at the origin.
Actually the use of polar coordinates should be avoided. All we need is a homeomorphims $\phi : [0,1) \to [0,\infty)$. We may take $\phi(t) = \frac{t}{1-t}$.
If $D^n$ is the open unit ball $\mathbb R^n$, we define
$$h : D^n \to \mathbb R^n, h(x) = \phi(\lVert x \rVert) x .$$
Here $\lVert - \rVert$ is the Euclidean norm. Obviously $h$ is a homeomorphism.

Yes this seems to be slightly incorrect. It would be better to replace $\frac 1{1-r}$ with $\frac 1{1-r}-1$, so maybe it was just a typo.
